# How to take data elements in a dataset and turn them into rows and columns?

Tags: r

Before I start off I should I have never used R until yesterday, I only know some Python and am very much a beginner. I'm using R because I cannot figure out how to do anything in excel, and have already had more progress with R.

So I have a seemingly unique problem I'm trying to solve. I have a data set that looks similar to this:

```
      ID     Contaminant     
 1    123    Lead            
 2    123    Copper          
 3    456    Lead            
 4    678    Iron            
 5    456    Lead            
 6    111    Iron            
 7    222    Arsenic
```

I want to take this data and create a new xlsx or csv file from it for data analysis. I want to see how many times the ID has had a contaminant and what that contaminant is. I (think) I have figured out how to figure out the unique values of how many ID's are associated with the Contaminant type and how many ID's have a unique Contaminant associated with them. If that makes sense.

I want the new data sheet to look something like this:

```
   ID     Lead     Copper     Iron     Arsenic
   123    1        2          0        0  
   456    2        0          0        0
   678    0        0          1        0
   111    0        0          1        0
   222    0        0          0        0
```

So far I have figured out how to take my original data sheet, which contains a lot of variables, and turn it into the first data set I listed above, that only contains IDs and Contaminants.

My code is a bit rough, as I'm mimicking others works, but what I have so far is:

```
violations <- tbl_df(2015_Violations)
new_violations <- select(violations, -TypeofViolation, -"CODETypeof Vio")

with(unique(violations[c("ID","Contaminant")]), table(Contaminant))
with(unique(violations[c("ID","Contaminant")]), table(ID))

write.csv(new_violations, file = "C:/r_stuff/new_violations.csv",
           row.names = F)
```

This spits out the unique numbers for Contaminants and ID's into some tables.

I am then using a different .R file to test this new .csv file. It simply contains this:

```
mydata <- read.csv("C:/r_stuff/new_violations.csv")
View(mydata)
```

So my question is, how can I take my data in the first table and turn it into a new file with the structure of the second? I assume this isn't a very easy task, but doing it by hand will be impossible as there is thousands of entries for the original data file.

Comment: try `as.data.frame.matrix(table(mydata))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to do it like that:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(ID, Contaminant) %>% 
  mutate(Count = n()) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Contaminant, values_from = Count) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate_all(replace_na, 0)
```

where:

```
data <-
  tibble(
    ID = c(123, 123, 456, 678, 456, 111, 222),
    Contaminant = c("Lead", "Copper", "Lead", "Iron", "Lead", "Iron", "Arsenic")
  )
```

It gives:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     ID  Lead Copper  Iron Arsenic
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1   123     1      1     0       0
2   456     2      0     0       0
3   678     0      0     1       0
4   111     0      0     1       0
5   222     0      0     0       1
```